# Can I split up my CSS / SASS webpack loader rules or do they need to be one big rule?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm adding SASS to my webpack config. I already have a CSS loader rule that looks like the following set of rules ...

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      "style-loader",
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          // https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader#importloaders
          importLoaders: 1
        }
      },
      "postcss-loader"
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts(x?)$/i,
    loader: "ts-loader",
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
  }
]
```

I want to introduce SASS to this, so I tried adding it before the CSS loader since SASS converts to CSS ...

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      "style-loader",
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          // https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader#importloaders
          importLoaders: 2
        }
      },
      "postcss-loader"
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/i,
    loader: "sass-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts(x?)$/i,
    loader: "ts-loader",
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
  }
]
```

I also changed `importLoaders` to 2 so that `css-loader` allows `sass-loader`, according to the docs.

This doesn't seem to work, though. It doesn't look like the CSS loader is picking up the CSS created by the SASS loader. I get the following error ...

> ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 228 KiB [built] [1 error]
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 1:0 Module parse
> failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) File was processed with these
> loaders:  * ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js You may need an
> additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
>
> > @charset "UTF-8"; | /*! |  * Bootstrap  v5.2.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)  @ ./src/index.tsx 1:0-39

Now, if I make this all one big rule for SASS and use these same loaders it all works ...

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      "style-loader",
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          // https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader#importloaders
          importLoaders: 2
        }
      },
      "postcss-loader",
      "sass-loader"
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts(x?)$/i,
    loader: "ts-loader",
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
  }
]
```

But now I've lost my CSS rule and to re-add it creates a basically identical rule to the SASS rule - loader-wise.

Why can't I split up these rules? I have both CSS and SASS.

Comment: You can combine css and scss in one rule: sass-loader should process css just fine. `test: /\.s?css$/,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanting to pass the generated file by one `rule` to another won't work. Their only job is to treat matching modules found in your code, they do nothing on generated files, which is kinda what [`plugins`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/#root) do, but more for minimizing, code splitting... The doc says about [`rules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulerules):

> An array of Rules which are matched to requests when [modules](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules) are created. These rules can modify how the module is created.

Notice the *"when modules are created"*, not after they are created, by passing through one rule as you want to do. The [`importLoader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#importloaders) is a way to deal with `@import` in CSS, not for controlling `rules` order:

> Allows to enables/disables or setups number of loaders applied before CSS loader for `@import` at-rules, CSS modules and ICSS imports, i.e. `@import`/`composes`/`@value value from './values.css'`/etc.

Now since any CSS code is valid SCSS code, you can simply combine the two files in one rule, treating them as if all of them were SCSS files. You can do that by changing the rule `test` RegExp to:

```js
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/, // to match .sass, .scss, and .css files
    use: [
      "style-loader",
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          // https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader#importloaders
          importLoaders: 2,
        },
      },
      "postcss-loader",
      "sass-loader",
    ],
  },
  // ...
]
```